# Unable to add reference to an F# PCL when using Universal Windows Platform client

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, portable-class-library

I am unable to add a reference to an F# PCL when using a Universal Windows Platform client.

Is this not supported?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# is not yet supported for .net native.

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/9110134-f-support-in-net-native-for-uwp